# Only removing a character one time from a string python 3

Tags: python, string, character

How can I remove a character from a string, but only once? This is my example:

```
string = "/file/file/file.jpg"
string = string.replace("/","")
```

This will remove all `"/"` from my string, but I only want it to remove the first one; how can I manage to do this?

Comment: Read the rest of the docs to `str.replace` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general: `str.replace()` takes a 3rd parameter, the count:

```
string.replace('/', '', 1)
```

From the [`str.replace()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>   [...] If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first *count* occurrences are replaced.

In your specific case, you could just use the [`str.lstrip()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) instead to remove slashes from the start:

```
string.lstrip('/')
```

This is subtly different; it'll remove *zero or more* such slashes from the start, and nowhere else.

Demo:

```
>>> string = "/file/file/file.jpg"
>>> string.replace('/', '', 1)
'file/file/file.jpg'
>>> string.lstrip('/')
'file/file/file.jpg'
```